# Dual samsung external monitors - "Not optimum mode"

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card, xorg

I have a Lenovo X1 Extreme device with two graphics cards

```
> lspci | grep -e VGA -e 3D
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
```

On which i am trying to connect two external [samsung monitors](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07PBBM8SW/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). The first monitor is connected via HDMI directly to the laptop, the other is connected to one of the USBC ports through an [HDMI->USBC cable](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07CL2RHX5/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1).

The monitor connected to the HDMI port works well. However, the one connected to the USBC port via the adapter cable reports "Not optimum mode, recommended mode is 1920x1080 60Hz". I switched the setup to make sure that both monitors work individually and they do.

Here's what xrandr reports:

```
>  xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.97    59.96    59.93
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88
   1400x1050     59.98
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82
   1280x1024     60.02
   1400x900      59.96    59.88
   1280x960      60.00
   1440x810      60.00    59.97
   1368x768      59.88    59.85
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74
   1024x768      60.04    60.00
   960x720       60.00
   928x696       60.05
   896x672       60.01
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82
   960x600       59.93    60.00
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25
   840x525       60.01    59.88
   864x486       59.92    59.57
   700x525       59.98
   800x450       59.95    59.82
   640x512       60.02
   700x450       59.96    59.88
   640x480       60.00    59.94
   720x405       59.51    58.99
   684x384       59.88    59.85
   640x400       59.88    59.98
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32
   512x384       60.00
   512x288       60.00    59.92
   480x270       59.63    59.82
   400x300       60.32    56.34
   432x243       59.92    59.57
   320x240       60.05
   360x202       59.51    59.13
   320x180       59.84    59.32
DP-1-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00
   1680x1050     59.95
   1600x900      60.00
   1440x900      59.89
   1280x1024     60.02
   1280x800      59.81
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00
   1024x768      70.07    60.00
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       59.94
   640x480       72.81    59.94
DP-1-1 disconnected
HDMI-1-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00
   1680x1050     59.95
   1600x900      60.00
   1440x900      59.89
   1280x1024     60.02
   1280x800      59.81
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00
   1024x768      70.07    60.00
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       59.94
   640x480       72.81    59.94
  1680x1050 (0x48) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
  1280x1024 (0x4f) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1280x800 (0x59) 83.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock  59.81Hz
  1024x768 (0x60) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x6f) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x70) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  640x480 (0x7c) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
```

Checking xorg.log for errors, i am not sure if the errors here are related:

```
[ 27592.478] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 5388
[ 27592.478] (II) modeset(0): DDCModeFromDetailedTiming: Ignoring tiny 852x0 mode
[ 27592.478] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[ 27592.478] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.78  1920 2000 2054 2080  1080 1086 1094 1112 -hsync -vsync (66.7 kHz eP)
[ 27601.488] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 5388
[ 27601.488] (II) modeset(0): DDCModeFromDetailedTiming: Ignoring tiny 852x0 mode
[ 27601.488] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[ 27601.488] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.78  1920 2000 2054 2080  1080 1086 1094 1112 -hsync -vsync (66.7 kHz eP)
[ 27601.497] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 5388
[ 27601.497] (II) modeset(0): DDCModeFromDetailedTiming: Ignoring tiny 852x0 mode
[ 27601.497] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[ 27601.497] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.78  1920 2000 2054 2080  1080 1086 1094 1112 -hsync -vsync (66.7 kHz eP)
[ 27601.498] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 5388
[ 27601.498] (II) modeset(0): DDCModeFromDetailedTiming: Ignoring tiny 852x0 mode
[ 27601.498] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[ 27601.498] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.78  1920 2000 2054 2080  1080 1086 1094 1112 -hsync -vsync (66.7 kHz eP)
[ 27601.498] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C27R502 (DFP-0): connected
[ 27601.498] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C27R502 (DFP-0): Internal DisplayPort
[ 27601.498] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C27R502 (DFP-0): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 27601.498] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[ 27601.498] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[ 27601.498] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal DisplayPort
[ 27601.498] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 27601.498] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[ 27601.528] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C27R502 (DFP-2): connected
[ 27601.528] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C27R502 (DFP-2): Internal TMDS
[ 27601.528] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C27R502 (DFP-2): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 27601.528] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[ 27605.474] (II) NVIDIA(G0): Setting mode "HDMI-1-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off, ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
[ 27605.541] (II) NVIDIA(G0): Setting mode "HDMI-1-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off, ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}, DP-1-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off, ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
[ 27605.803] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 5388
[ 27605.803] (II) modeset(0): DDCModeFromDetailedTiming: Ignoring tiny 852x0 mode
[ 27605.803] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[ 27605.803] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.78  1920 2000 2054 2080  1080 1086 1094 1112 -hsync -vsync (66.7 kHz eP)
[ 27605.804] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 5388
[ 27605.804] (II) modeset(0): DDCModeFromDetailedTiming: Ignoring tiny 852x0 mode
[ 27605.804] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[ 27605.804] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.78  1920 2000 2054 2080  1080 1086 1094 1112 -hsync -vsync (66.7 kHz eP)
[ 27605.805] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C27R502 (DFP-0): connected
[ 27605.805] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C27R502 (DFP-0): Internal DisplayPort
[ 27605.805] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C27R502 (DFP-0): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 27605.805] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[ 27605.805] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[ 27605.805] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal DisplayPort
[ 27605.805] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 27605.805] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[ 27605.834] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C27R502 (DFP-2): connected
[ 27605.834] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C27R502 (DFP-2): Internal TMDS
[ 27605.834] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C27R502 (DFP-2): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 27605.834] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[ 28179.571] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-4ms), your system is too slow
[ 28218.159] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-11ms), your system is too slow
[ 28246.772] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-3ms), your system is too slow
[ 28432.423] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-4ms), your system is too slow
[ 28452.090] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-6ms), your system is too slow
[ 28463.087] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-2ms), your system is too slow
[ 28463.087] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-15ms), your system is too slow
[ 28479.662] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-2ms), your system is too slow
[ 28479.662] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-15ms), your system is too slow
[ 28586.726] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-5ms), your system is too slow
[ 28822.462] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-3ms), your system is too slow
[ 28822.462] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-16ms), your system is too slow
[ 28861.623] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-1ms), your system is too slow
[ 28861.623] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-14ms), your system is too slow
[ 28868.065] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-3ms), your system is too slow
[ 28899.677] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-8ms), your system is too slow
[ 28921.765] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-11ms), your system is too slow
[ 28921.865] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-13ms), your system is too slow
[ 28921.865] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-26ms), your system is too slow
[ 28928.379] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-2ms), your system is too slow
[ 28928.474] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-5ms), your system is too slow
[ 28947.766] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-6ms), your system is too slow
[ 29013.450] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-3ms), your system is too slow
[ 29024.328] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-6ms), your system is too slow
[ 29025.626] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-9ms), your system is too slow
[ 29025.626] (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-22ms), your system is too slow
[ 29118.747] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 5388
[ 29118.747] (II) modeset(0): DDCModeFromDetailedTiming: Ignoring tiny 852x0 mode
[ 29118.747] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[ 29118.747] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.78  1920 2000 2054 2080  1080 1086 1094 1112 -hsync -vsync (66.7 kHz eP)
[ 29118.749] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 5388
[ 29118.749] (II) modeset(0): DDCModeFromDetailedTiming: Ignoring tiny 852x0 mode
[ 29118.749] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[ 29118.749] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.78  1920 2000 2054 2080  1080 1086 1094 1112 -hsync -vsync (66.7 kHz eP)
[ 29118.750] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C27R502 (DFP-0): connected
[ 29118.750] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C27R502 (DFP-0): Internal DisplayPort
[ 29118.750] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C27R502 (DFP-0): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 29118.750] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[ 29118.750] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[ 29118.750] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal DisplayPort
[ 29118.750] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
```

The way my laptop is setup is that i have the official nvidia driver installed. However, i don't have xf86-video-intel driver. I have the following script that lightdm runs on startup:

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto
```

What do i have to do in order to have both monitors work? what is the problem to begin with? i am not exactly sure what the problem is therefore, i don't know if there's anything i can change to fix this issue.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like my BIOS setting had display on "Hybrid". After switching this to "Discrete", both monitors now work without issues.